# JADE/PUG: Unable to use two mixins

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am using mixin in my jade file. The requirement is to have two divs. If I create only a single div it renders but if I use two mixins to render the content I get error: "undefined jade_mixins.selectedImage-card is not a function"

Here is the jade code:

```
.container
        .allThumbs
          h2 All 
          .row
           mixin allImage-card(photo)
            .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-6
              .imgThumb
                img.thumb(src=photo.URL, alt="")

        for photo in _allPhotos
          +allImage-card(photo)

        .allThumbs
          h2 Selected
          .row
            mixin selectedImage-card(photo)
            .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-6
              .imgThumb
                img.thumb(src=photo.URL, alt="")

        for photo in _selected
          +selectedImage-card(photo)
```

Comment: you should put mixin code outside the indentation, something like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is your indentation. Putting your code in a compiler results in the following error:

```
  > 24|             mixin selectedImage-card(photo)
--------------------^
    25|             .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-6
    26|               .imgThumb
    27|                 img.thumb(src=photo.URL, alt="")

Mixin selectedImage-card declared without body
```

Give an additional leading space, after declaring the mixin, and it will work.

Ideally, you should define mixins at the beginning of the file, and refer them at a later stage as suggested [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630429/jade-pug-unable-to-use-two-mixins/44630568#comment76246621_44630429).

Answer (score 0):

Put the mixin code outside the indentation.

Example:

```
mixin allImage-card(photo)
   .example 
      !{photo.name}

mixin selectedImage-card(photo)
   .test 
      !{photo.name}


.container
    -var _allPhotos = [{'name':'john'}, {'name': 'fred'}]
    -var _selected = [{'name':'luka'}, {'name': 'lisa'}]

    for photo in _allPhotos
      +allImage-card(photo)

    .allThumbs
      h2 Selected
      .row
    for photo in _selected
      +selectedImage-card(photo)
```